# Flex 4 app preloader takes several seconds to show up (loads quickly after that)

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flash-builder, performance

I'm somewhere between novice and intermediate levels with Flex and brand new to Flex 4. I've built a magazine app for a client that pulls in dynamic issue information and generates a book using the qs FlexBook component. The problem is that the app seems to take forever to BEGIN loading.

The app progress bar does not display for several seconds. Once it finally shows up, the app loads quickly. The file sizes don't seem overly large to me and the issue remains whether I use RSLs, merge the code or convert it to a module. You can see the effect here: http://whosthatnerd.com/clients/jones/issues/

Here is my MXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               preloader="mx.preloaders.DownloadProgressBar"
               skinClass="skins.TransparentAppSkin"
               creationComplete="init()"
               minWidth="955"
               minHeight="600">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
        @namespace qsctrl "qs.controls.*";
        qsctrl|FlexBook {
            hardbackCovers: false;
            paddingTop: 0;
            paddingRight: 0;
            paddingBottom: 0;
            paddingLeft: 0;
            paddingSpine: 0;
            color: #000000;
            textRollOverColor:  #000000;
            edgeAndCornerSize: 70;
            background-color: #000000;
        }
        mx|HBox {
            paddingTop: 0;
            paddingBottom: 0;
            paddingLeft: 0;
            paddingRight: 0;
            horizontalGap: 0;
        }
        mx|Image {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        mx|ProgressBar {
            color: #EEEEEE;
        }
    </fx:Style>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.containers.HBox;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.controls.Image;
            import mx.core.IUIComponent;
            import mx.core.UIComponent;
            import mx.events.ResizeEvent;

            import qs.controls.FlexBook;

            private var issueID:String;
            private var xmlLoader:URLLoader;
            private var xml:XML;
            private var swfLoader:Loader;
            private var swfClass:Class;
            private var book:FlexBook;
            public var pageHeight:int = 890;
            public var pageWidth:int = 600;

            private function init():void {

                loadingIndicator.x = appCanvas.width / 2 - loadingIndicator.width / 2;
                loadingIndicator.y = appCanvas.height / 2 - loadingIndicator.height / 2;

                issueID = parameters.issue_id;

                xmlLoader = new URLLoader();

                xmlLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
                xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fillBook);

                xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest('/clients/jones/issues/issues/view/'+issueID+'.xml'));

            }

            public function progressHandler(e:ProgressEvent):void {

                loadingIndicator.setProgress(e.bytesLoaded, e.bytesTotal);
                loadingIndicator.label = 'Loading Publication... '+Math.round(e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal * 100).toString();

            }

            private function scaleBook(e:* = null):void {

                book.height = Math.ceil((appCanvas.height * 0.9));
                book.width = Math.floor((book.height * 1.491285403050109));
                book.y = appCanvas.height / 2 - book.height / 2;
                book.x = appCanvas.width / 2 - book.width / 2;

            }

            private function fillBook(e:Event):void {

                xml = new XML(e.target.data);

                if(xml.use_swf == 1) {

                    trace('loading: '+xml.swf);

                    swfLoader = new Loader();
                    swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, useExternalSwf);
                    swfLoader.load(new URLRequest(xml.swf));


                } else {

                    usePageImages(xml);

                }

                publicationName.text = xml.publication.name;

                var d:Array = String(xml.pub_date).split('-');

                issueDate.text = 'Published: '+d[1]+'/'+d[2]+'/'+d[0];

            }

            public function prepareDisplay():void {

                loadingIndicator.visible = false;

                bookDetails.x = book.x;
                bookDetails.y = book.y;
                bookDetails.width = book.width / 2;
                bookDetails.height = book.height;


                bookDetails.visible = true;

            }

            public function usePageImages(xml:XML):void {

                book = new FlexBook();
                book.itemSize = 'halfPage';
                scaleBook();

                var box:HBox;
                var img:Image;
                var pages:Array = new Array();

                for(var i:int = 0; i < xml.page.length(); i++) {

                    trace(i);
                    trace(xml.page[i].image_url);

                    box = new HBox();
                    box.horizontalScrollPolicy = 'off';
                    box.verticalScrollPolicy = 'off';
                    img = new Image();
                    img.maintainAspectRatio = true;
                    img.percentHeight = 100;
                    img.percentWidth = 100;
                    img.source = xml.page[i].image_url;
                    box.addChild(img);

                    if(i == 0) {

                        book.cover = box;

                    } else if(i+1 == xml.page.length()) {

                        book.backCover = box;

                    } else {

                        book.addChild(box);
                        pages.push(box);

                    }

                }

                book.content = pages;

                appCanvas.addElement(book);

                prepareDisplay();

                appCanvas.addEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, scaleBook);

            }

            public function useExternalSwf(e:Event):void {

                trace('LOADED SWF');

                book = new FlexBook();
                book.itemSize = 'halfPage';
                scaleBook();

                var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(swfLoader.content);

                swfClass = mc.constructor;

                var dupe:MovieClip;
                var comp:UIComponent;
                var box:HBox;
                var pages:Array = new Array();


                for(var i:int = 0; i < mc.totalFrames; i++) {

                    dupe = MovieClip(new mc.constructor);
                    dupe.gotoAndStop(i);

                    comp = new UIComponent();
                    comp.addChild(dupe);

                    box = new HBox();
                    box.addChild(comp);
                    box.horizontalScrollPolicy = 'off';
                    box.verticalScrollPolicy = 'off';

                    dupe.width = comp.width = book.width / 2;
                    dupe.height = comp.height = book.height;

                    if(i == 0) {

                        book.cover = box;

                    } else if(i+1 == xml.page.length()) {

                        book.backCover = box;

                    } else {

                        book.addChild(box);
                        pages.push(box);

                    }

                }

                book.content = pages;

                appCanvas.addElement(book);

                prepareDisplay();

                appCanvas.addEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, scaleBook);

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:BorderContainer id="bookDetails" visible="false">
        <s:backgroundFill>
            <s:LinearGradient>
                <s:entries>
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x707070" ratio="0.00" alpha="1" />
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x505050" ratio="0.75" alpha="1" />
                </s:entries>
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:backgroundFill>
        <s:borderStroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke joints="miter" color="0x101010" weight="12" /> 
        </s:borderStroke>
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="18" paddingRight="18" paddingBottom="18" paddingLeft="18" />
        </s:layout>
        <s:Label id="publicationName" fontSize="32" fontWeight="bold" color="0xEEEEEE" alpha="1" />
        <mx:Text id="issueDate" fontSize="20" color="0xEEEEEE" alpha="1" />
        <mx:Text id="bookInstructions" fontSize="20" color="0xEEEEEE" alpha="1" text="Click or drag the corners to turn the page." />
    </s:BorderContainer>

    <s:BorderContainer id="appCanvas" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" skinClass="skins.TransparentAppSkin"></s:BorderContainer>

    <mx:ProgressBar id="loadingIndicator" label="Loading Publication..."/>

</s:Application>
```

I honestly don't know if the issue is my player or my code. Thanks in advance for your help :)